# Factorial tail recursion returns vague number

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

I'm trying out a factorial tail recursive program, if I enter number 4, the factorial of it should printed out, but instead 32767 is printed out always.
What's wrong with this code? and Why does it print out 32767 ?

```
int factTR(unsigned int n, unsigned int a)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return factTR(n - 1, n * a);
    }

    int fact(unsigned int n);
    {
        return factTR(n, 1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("hi\n");

    unsigned int a, n;

    printf("Enter a positive number : ");
    scanf("%u", &n);
    factTR(n, a);

    printf("The factorial of %u is %u", n, a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialized `a`.

Comment: Nested functions aren't allowed in standard C. Defined `fact` outside `factTR`.

Comment: You have a function `fact` inside `factTR` that you never use.  I suspect this is not what you meant to do.

Comment: What you probably meant to do was call `fact()` from `main()`. It provides the proper initial value of `a` in the recursion.

Comment: The `factTR(n, a)` call in `main` passes an uninitialized value of `a` and it discards the return value.  Should be `a = factTR(n, 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an uninitialized value of `a` to `factTR()`.

`factTR()` is intended to be called from `fact()`, which provides the proper initial value in the recursion.

Then in `main()` you should use the return value to get the result. C parameters are passed by value, so using `a` as an argument won't update its value.

```
nt factTR(unsigned int n, unsigned int a)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return factTR(n - 1, n * a);
    }

}

int fact(unsigned int n);
{
    return factTR(n, 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("hi\n");

    unsigned int a, n;

    printf("Enter a positive number : ");
    scanf("%u", &n);
    a = fact(n);

    printf("The factorial of %u is %u", n, a);

    return 0;
}
```